# calling a thread sleep or wait inside a grails bootstrap file shows error

Tags: java, groovy

I'm having problems calling `Thread.CurrentThread.sleep(0.5*1000)`

When ever I do this:

```
import java.lang.Thread.*;    
Thread.currentThread().sleep(0.3*1000)
// or Thread.currentThread().sleep(0.3*1000.toLong())
```

I get the following error:

```
No signature of method: java.lang.Thread.sleep() is applicable for argument types: (java.math.BigDecimal) values: [300.0]
Possible solutions: sleep(long), sleep(long), sleep(long, int), sleep(long, groovy.lang.Closure), stop(), grep()
```

What would you recommend ?

Comment: if it's `0.3 * 1000` and it's always `0.3 * 1000`, why not put `300`?

Comment: You also don't need `import java.lang.Thread.*`

Comment: i did not need to import Thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you are providing as the argument: `0.3*1000` refers to multiplication (float*int= float), the result is then inferred Float type.

You should provide a long argument as the parameter of sleep function, and you can achieve this by simply casting the expression result:

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)(0.3*1000));
```

Comment: With Groovy, the result is `BigDecimal`, not `Float`